# No mime type could be found for file /https://a-website.com using Glassfish 4.1 and Java 7

Tags: java, glassfish, mime-types

I am using HttpURLConnection to download the content of a website, I used google as an example. Everything works as expected but I get the following warning

```
 Warning:   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /https://google.com.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
    Warning:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /https://google.com.
```

Here is how i am doing http connect in the managed bean:

```
 public String doHTTPsConnect() throws Exception {
System.out.println("This is the URL " + url);
        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }

        bf.close();
        return "url";
    }
```

the full output:

```
Info:   This is the URL https://google.com
Info:   <!doctype html><html dir="rtl" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ar"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.2-5733935958982656-ror.jpg" itemprop="image"><meta content="#GoogleDoodle 2016 íæã ÇáÃÑÖ" property="og:description"><meta content="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.4-thp.png" property="og:image"><meta content="700" property="og:image:width"><meta content="220" property="og:image:height"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'xSsaV-avF8eqsgGijBQ',kEXPI:'1350654,1350656,1350793,1350858,3700062,3700260,3700388,4029815,4031109,4032677,4036509,4036527,4038012,4039268,4042553,4042784,4042792,4043492,4045341,4045841,4048347,4049550,4049558,4051159,4053233,4054552,4054591,4056038,4056484,4057170,4057739,4057836,4058337,4059767,4061155,4061181,4061303,4061922,4062222,4062299,4062333,4062407,4062631,4062789,4063096,4063111,4063125,4063333,4063361,4063363,4063735,4063879,4063972,4064058,4064096,4064318,4064449,4064494,4064501,4064702,4064828,4065112,4065284,4065591,4065752,8300272,8502946,8503585,8503926,8503928,8503932,8503934,8504107,8504111,8504296,8504424,8504456,10200083,10200096,10201288,10201819,10201832',authuser:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_24'};google.kHL='ar';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(c){}};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,c,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,c,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var d=google.lc,f=google.li;d[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete d[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,c,e,g){var d="",f=google.ls||"";if(!c&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){var h=google.getEI(e),d="&ei="+h;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?d+="&lei="+e:h!=google.kEI&&(d+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=c||"/"+(g||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+d+f+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.load=function(a,b,c){google.x({id:a+k++},function(){google.load(a,b,c)})};var k=0;})();var _gjwl=location;function _gjuc(){var a=_gjwl.href.indexOf("#");if(0<=a&&(a=_gjwl.href.substring(a),0<a.indexOf("&q=")||0<=a.indexOf("#q="))&&(a=a.substring(1),-1==a.indexOf("#"))){for(var d=0;d<a.length;){var b=d;"&"==a.charAt(b)&&++b;var c=a.indexOf("&",b);-1==c&&(c=a.length);b=a.substring(b,c);if(0==b.indexOf("fp="))a=a.substring(0,d)+a.substring(c,a.length),c=d;else if("cad=h"==b)return 0;d=c}_gjwl.href="/search?"+a+"&cad=h";return 1}return 0}
Info:   function _gjh(){!_gjuc()&&window.google&&google.x&&google.x({id:"GJH"},function(){google.nav&&google.nav.gjh&&google.nav.gjh()})};window._gjh&&_gjh();</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:left}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-left:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:right}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
Info:   </style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#36c}.q{color:#00c}.ts td{padding:0}.ts{border-collapse:collapse}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-right:4px}input{font-family:inherit}a.gb1,a.gb2,a.gb3,a.gb4{color:#11c !important}body{background:#fff;color:black}a{color:#11c;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#36c}a:visited{color:#551a8b}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline}a.gb3:hover{text-decoration:none}#ghead a.gb2:hover{color:#fff !important}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-right:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#eee;border:solid 1px;border-color:#ccc #ccc #999 #999;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}.ftl,#fll a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;border:none;color:#000;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#ccc}.lst:focus{outline:none}.tiah{width:458px}</style><script></script><link href="/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico" rel="shortcut icon"></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script>(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo229.png';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}
Info:   if (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}
Info:   }
Warning:   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file /https://google.com.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
Warning:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /https://google.com.
Info:   })();</script><div id="mngb">    <div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>ÈÍË</b> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.google.com.eg/imghp?hl=ar&tab=wi">ÕæÑ</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://maps.google.com.eg/maps?hl=ar&tab=wl">ÎÑÇÆØ</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EG&tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://news.google.com.eg/nwshp?hl=ar&ned=ar_me&tab=wn">ÇáÃÎÈÇÑ</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.google.com/calendar?tab=wc">ÊÞæíã</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.com.eg/intl/ar/options/"><u>ÇáãÒíÏ</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.com.eg/history/optout?hl=ar" class=gb4>ÓöÌá ÈÍË ÇáæíÈ</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=ar" class=gb4>ÇáÅÚÏÇÏÇÊ</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=ar&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com.eg/%3Fgfe_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3DxCsaV_aMOI2x8weJnJnIBQ" class=gb4>ÊÓÌíá ÇáÏÎæá</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div>    </div><center><br clear="all" id="lgpd"><div id="lga"><a href="/search?site=&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;q=2016+%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B1%D8%B6&amp;oi=ddle&amp;ct=earth-day-2016-5741289212477440&amp;hl=ar&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwimppKzsaLMAhVHlSwKHSIGBQAQNggD"><img alt="2016 íæã ÇáÃÑÖ" border="0" height="220" src="/logos/doodles/2016/earth-day-2016-5741289212477440.2-5733935958982656-ror.jpg" title="2016 íæã ÇáÃÑÖ" width="700" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&&lol()"><br></a><br></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" value="windows-1256" type="hidden"><input value="ar" name="hl" type="hidden"><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"><input name="biw" type="hidden"><input name="bih" type="hidden"><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><div style="position:relative;zoom:1"><input style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 6px 0 8px;vertical-align:top;padding-left:38px" autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="" title="ÈÍË Googleþ" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57"><img src="/textinputassistant/tia.png" style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;left:5px;top:4px;z-index:300" onclick="(function(){var src='/textinputassistant/11/ar_tia.js';var s=document.createElement('script');s.src=src;google.dom.append(s);})();" alt="" height="23" width="27"></div></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="ÈÍË Googleþ" name="btnG" type="submit"></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="ÖÑÈÉ ÍÙ" name="btnI" onclick="if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location='/doodles/'" type="submit"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="right" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=ar&amp;authuser=0">ÈÍË ãÊÞÏã</a><a href="/language_tools?hl=ar&amp;authuser=0">ÃÏæÇÊ ÇááÛÉ</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br><div id="als"><style>#als{font-size:small;margin-bottom:24px}#_eEe{display:inline-block;line-height:28px;}#_eEe a{padding:0 3px;}._lEe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px;white-space:nowrap}._PEe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px}</style><div id="_eEe">ÇáäØÇÞ <span dir="ltr">Google.com.eg</span> ãÊæÝÑ ÈÇááÛÇÊ: <a dir="ltr" href="https://www.google.com.eg/setprefs?sig=0_ME55CtU_LhI2XY4Ahh-RzhAxNKg%3D&amp;hl=en&amp;source=homepage" data-ved="0ahUKEwimppKzsaLMAhVHlSwKHSIGBQAQ2ZgBCAU">English</a> </div></div></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center" id="fll"><a href="/intl/ar/ads/">ÇáÈÑäÇãÌ ÇáÅÚáÇäí</a><a href="http://www.google.com/intl/ar/services/">Íáæá ÇáÔÑßÇÊ</a><a href="https://plus.google.com/101532581614261957891" rel="publisher">ý+Google</a><a href="/intl/ar/about.html">ßá ãÇ ÊÍÈ ãÚÑÝÊå Úä Googleþ åäÇ</a><a dir="ltr" href="https://www.google.com.eg/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&amp;sig=__SGEPdS81iUc2-fRNZqTG4Ho2gP8%3D" id="fehl">Google.com</a></div></div><p style="color:#767676;font-size:8pt">&copy; 2016 - <a href="/intl/ar/policies/privacy/">ÇáÎÕæÕíÉ</a> - <a href="/intl/ar/policies/terms/">ÇáÈäæÏ</a></p></span></center><script>(function(){window.google.cdo={height:0,width:0};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b)var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body,a=d.clientWidth,b=d.clientHeight;a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);})();})();</script><div id="xjsd"></div><div id="xjsi"><script>(function(){function c(b){window.setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src=b;document.getElementById("xjsd").appendChild(a)},0)}google.dljp=function(b,a){google.xjsu=b;c(a)};google.dlj=c;})();(function(){window.google.xjsrm=[];})();if(google.y)google.y.first=[];if(!google.xjs){window._=window._||{};window._._DumpException=function(e){throw e};if(google.timers&&google.timers.load.t){google.timers.load.t.xjsls=new Date().getTime();}google.dljp('/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.fmJjeDpKhlY.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oGzKbyXaRnPCWgVR4dBFQ9dV2gEnQ','/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en_US.fmJjeDpKhlY.O/m\x3dsb_he,d/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oGzKbyXaRnPCWgVR4dBFQ9dV2gEnQ');google.xjs=1;}google.pmc={"sb_he":{"agen":true,"cgen":true,"client":"heirloom-hp","dh":true,"dhqt":true,"ds":"","fl":true,"host":"google.com.eg","isbh":28,"jam":0,"jsonp":true,"msgs":{"cibl":"ãÍæ ÇáÈÍË","dym":"åá ÊÞÕÏ :","lcky":"ÖÑÈÉ ÍÙ","lml":"ãÒíÏ ãä ÇáãÚáæãÇÊ","oskt":"ÃÏæÇÊ ÇáÅÏÎÇá","psrc":"ÊãÊ ÅÒÇáÉ åÐÇ ÇáÈÍË ãä \u003Ca href=\"/history\"\u003EÓöÌá ÇáÈÍË\u003C/a\u003E.","psrl":"ÅÒÇáÉ","sbit":"ÇáÈÍË ÈÍÓÈ ÇáÕæÑ","srch":"ÈÍË Googleþ"},"ovr":{},"pq":"","refpd":true,"rfs":[],"scd":10,"sce":5,"stok":"wU0XUPEaonrMpwEu-7WqsJDBKx4"},"d":{}};google.y.first.push(function(){if(google.med){google.med('init');google.initHistory();google.med('history');}});if(google.j&&google.j.en&&google.j.xi){window.setTimeout(google.j.xi,0);}
Info:   </script></div></body></html>
```